# Property name on object from variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way in typescript to set a property name from a variable?

Something like this

```
export function objectFactory(prop: string) {
    return {
        prop: {
            valid: false
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question more than once.  The accepted answer is perfect but the question is what got me here :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are looking for [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), this is an ES6 feature and not specific to TypeScript.

```
export function objectFactory(prop: string) {
    return {
        [prop]: {
            valid: false
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
export function objectFactory(prop: string) {
    let data: any = {};
    data[prop] = {};
    data[prop].valid = false;
    return data;
}
```