# Using a variable's value in a MongoDB operation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run the following operation:

```
db[coll].update({'_id': "CNY.XX.X" },{ $unset: {"20201030": 1 }});
```

to update a collection and remove field: "20201030" from a document,
which works and removes field "20201030",

Now, I want to store "20201030" in a variable, and use that in the operation instead, but if I run:

```
   id_val = "CNY.XX.X.";
   date = "20201030";
   db[coll].update({'_id': id_val },{ $unset: {date: 1 }});
```

this does not work because field "20201030" is still there. Does anyone happen to know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property name on object from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050957/property-name-on-object-from-variable)

Comment: Are you using the native Mongo shell, Node.js?

Comment: What is most likely happening is the field name is processed as being the string `'date'`, rather than the value of the variable `date`. Depending on what environment you are in, there are different ways of evaluating the variable in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables as query.

Now, I'm going to assume you are using Node.js (and maybe mongoose) so a way to do your work is create a new object.

Note that `$unset: {"20201030": 1 }` is like `$unset : object` where the object is `{"20201030": 1 }`. So you have to create that object in this way:

```js
var queryParam = {};
queryParam["20201030"] = 1;
db[coll].update({'_id': "CNY.XX.X"},{"$unset":queryParam})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, that challenge had been driven me crazy all day yesterday (lol). I really appreciate it!